# How to test payable/external method with waffle and ethers.js

Tags: ethereum, vyper, ethers.js

Here is the smart contract, written in vyper,  to be tested

```
owner: public(address) 
name: public(String[100])
total_amount: uint256

@external
def __init__(_name: String[100]):
    self.owner = tx.origin 
    self.name = _name

@external
@payable
def donate():
#anyone can donate to the piggy bank
    self.total_amount += msg.value

@external
@view
def get_total_amount() -> uint256:
    return self.total_amount
```

What is the right way to test the `donate()` method of the smart contract with waffle and ethers.js?

Is there a sendTransaction method for ethers.js that can be called on contract's side like in this example of [web3+truffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740950/how-to-send-wei-eth-to-contract-address-using-truffle-javascript-test) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `overrides` parameter. It's used after all contract function arguments.

In your case, the contract function has 0 arguments so the `overrides` is on position 1.

```
let overrides = {
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
};
let tx = await myContract.donate(overrides);
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/563#issuecomment-513599929) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 
Appreciate this!